# Pipe online IP addresses to Python Fabric

Tags: python, python-2.7, fabric

I'm using Nmap to find all online hosts on a network. I'd like to then pipe these results to Fabric in order to perform commands on all those that are online.

My Nmap command is: `nmap -n -sn 192.168.40.0/24 -oG - | awk '/Up$/{print $2}'`

How would I use the results of this as input to a Fabric command?

Answer (score 0):

You can read data from sys.stdin, for example:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    print("Received line %s" % line)
    ... process received lines ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already have the IP addresses displayed by using awk. What I would like is to import them as an array of IPs.

Comment: Well.. just store input as a list, for example: `ips = sys.stdin.readlines()` and process it as you need. So the command will look like `nmap ... | awk ... | fabric_script.py` or just get output directly from nmap and process it in your script `nmap ... | fabric_script.py`